# How do I count only valid jquery file uploads?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image-processing

I'm trying to refresh my upload page after multiple image uploads using [jquery file upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options).

I'm currently counting the number of files added and then if they match the number of successful uploads then I refresh the page.  This works great until a user tries to upload an invalid file type or a too small of an image.  How can I include these failures as part of my total count? Is there a preferred method to do this?

```
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(jpe?g|png)$/i
    });

    var filesqueued = null; 
    var filesuploaded = 0;

    $('#fileupload').bind('fileuploadadd', function (e, data) {
        filesqueued = data.originalFiles.length;
    });


    $('#fileupload').bind('fileuploaddone', function (e, data) {
        filesuploaded = filesuploaded + 1;

        if (filesuploaded == filesqueued) {
            filesuploaded = 0;
            location.reload();
        }
    })
```

Comment: I will assume that you do your validation server side. What is your response for "invalid" file upload? Based on the response you can update your count inside 'fileuploaddone' callback.

Comment: For file types the validation is done client side.  I've added that block of code to the example above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use jQuery file upload's built-in events to bind success and fail events:

```
$('#fileupload').bind('fileuploadcompleted', function (e, data) {
    /* Successful upload */
        filesuploaded = filesuploaded + 1;
});

$('#fileupload').bind('fileuploadfailed', function (e, data) {
    /* Failed upload */
    // [...]
});
```

More here from their documentation: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options

Alternatively, you can do everything server-side. Have your upload handler (jQuery file upload's `url` option) respond:

```
<?php
if ( $valid == false ) {
    echo 'invalid';
    // or echo( json_encode( array( 'result' => 'invalid' ) ) );
}
```

Then back in jQuery analyze the data returned:

```
$('#fileupload').bind('fileuploaddone', function (e, data) {
    /* Check returned data */
    // Could use JSON or simple text output
    // if ( data.result == 'invalid' ) {
    if ( data == 'invalid' ) {
        // file did not pass
    } else {
        // file uploaded fine
        filesuploaded = filesuploaded + 1;
    }

    if (filesuploaded == filesqueued) {
        filesuploaded = 0;
        location.reload();
    }
})
```